# Validating a number in HTML input via JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Validating a number in `input` doesn't work, here's the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/aVF7M/

```
$('.number').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('keyup change',function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''));
    });
});


$('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    num()
    var $class = '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[0];
    var size_un = $($class).length;
    var $this = $(this),
        $div = $this.closest($class),
        $clone = $div.clone().hide().insertAfter($div).fadeIn('slow');
    $clone.find('.remove_table').remove();
    $clone.find('.adda').not(':has(.remove_input)').append('<div class="mediumCell"><a href="" class="remove_input"></a></div>');
    $clone.find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $clone.find('input:text').val('')
    $this.remove();
    var size_un = $($class).length---1;
    $($class + ':last input:checkbox').prop('name', 'checkbox_units[' + size_un + '][]');
    console.log($($class + ':last input:checkbox').prop('name'));
});
```

Comment: Can you please clean up your code and only provide as much as is relevant to the problem at hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have defined num() and it works.

As you are adding the input.number dynamically you would need to use live -

```
$('.number').live('keyup change',function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''));
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/aVF7M/1/

Comment: All those jQuery objects and function calls to get and set a property that can be accessed directly: `this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')` is very much faster.